# How to make a heading title with a clickable form inline?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a header consisting of a title (label "Manual Control") and a clickable red form or button ("Back") that are inline (width proportion: 75% to 25%). The total width of the page should not exceed 420px.

This is like it should look:

[image]

I tried it with a surrounding `<div class='heading'>` tag and the following CSS code:

```
.heading {
  width: 100%;
}
.heading div, form {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
```

But this ends up looking like this:

[image]

The sliders at the bottom are also too narrow. They should expand from the left to the right and be ordered one below the other (like depicted in the first image).

Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/salocinx/rub5jLhn/

**Requirements:**

- entire page width max 420px
- heading inline ("Manual Control" and "Back")
- remaining page as "block"
- sliders full length of page

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no'/>
        <title>Menu Test</title>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src='websocket.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='frame'>
            <div class='heading'>
              <div class='title'>
                  Manual Control
              </div>
              <form method='post' action='/' class='back'>
                  Back
              </form>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
            </div>
            <div class='title'>
                Gadget
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class='enabled_red' id='r0' type='range' min='0' max='1023' step='1' oninput='sendRGB(0);' value='0'>
                <input class='enabled_green' id='g0' type='range' min='0' max='1023' step='1' oninput='sendRGB(0);' value='0'>
                <input class='enabled_blue' id='b0' type='range' min='0' max='1023' step='1' oninput='sendRGB(0);' value='0'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  font-size:1em;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.frame {
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #444;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #d1d1d1;
  display: block;
}
.heading {
  width: 100%;
}
.heading div, form {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
div.title {
  border: 0;
  font-size:1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4C6DAF;
  padding: 18px;
}
form.back {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  font-size:1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #CB4C4C;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
}
div.logo {
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px;
}
/*input {
  width:100%;
  font-size:1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border-color: #d1d1d1;
  margin: 12px 0px;
  padding: 12px 0px 12px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
} */
button {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 0px;
}
button:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
form.back:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

/* ___________________________________ COLOURS __________________________________ */

.red {
  background-color: #CB4C4C;
}
.green {
  background-color: #4DB248;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #5591E3;
}

/* ____________________________________ SLIDER ___________________________________ */

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 16px 16px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.enabled_red[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #CB4C4C;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.enabled_green[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #4DB248;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.enabled_blue[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #5591E3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.disabled[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #999999;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: inherit;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
input.enabled[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Tried lots of different approaches, but I am really out of luck. Could somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Please include the necessary code in the question itself instead of an external snippet.

Comment: @Santi. Done. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't your back button actually be `button` or `input`?

Comment: As a reminder (it may have been intentional, in which case, no worries), the selector `.heading div, form` is **not** the same as `.heading div, .heading form`. Commas in CSS do not inherit anything from the prior selector.

Comment: @hungerstar: Yes I will change that to `button` or `input`. Thanks.
@ Santi: I will study the CSS selectors again, it's quite complex for a CSS newbie like me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using some unecessary floating. You can use flex for the heading like this :

```
.heading {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.heading>div {
  flex: 4;
}
.heading>form {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Also wrap the input ranges inside a container and use flex like this :

```
.container-input {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

Full code :

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.frame {
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #444;
  text-align: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #d1d1d1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.heading {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.heading>div {
  flex: 4;
}
.heading>form {
  flex: 1;
}

div.title {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4C6DAF;
  padding: 18px;
}

form.back {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #CB4C4C;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
}

div.logo {
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px;
}

.container-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding:10px 0;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 0px;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

form.back:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}


/* ___________________________________ COLOURS __________________________________ */

.red {
  background-color: #CB4C4C;
}

.green {
  background-color: #4DB248;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #5591E3;
}


/* ____________________________________ SLIDER ___________________________________ */

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 16px 16px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.enabled_red[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #CB4C4C;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.enabled_green[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #4DB248;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.enabled_blue[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #5591E3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.disabled[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #999999;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: inherit;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

input.enabled[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div class='heading'>
      <div class='title'>
        Manual Control
      </div>
      <form method='post' action='/' class='back'>
        Back
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
      Gadget
    </div>
    <div class='container-input'>
      <input class='enabled_red' id='r0' type='range' min='0' max='1023' step='1' oninput='sendRGB(0);' value='0'>
      <input class='enabled_green' id='g0' type='range' min='0' max='1023' step='1' oninput='sendRGB(0);' value='0'>
      <input class='enabled_blue' id='b0' type='range' min='0' max='1023' step='1' oninput='sendRGB(0);' value='0'>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you very much! Will play around with flex :-)

Comment: @salocinx yes i advice you to look into it as you can easily manage all your layout with simple property rather than using complicated stuffs like floating, etc

Comment: Flex was added in CSS v3, but I guess that's okay nowadays. CSS3 will work on all modern browsers, correct?

Comment: @salocinx yes flex is support by all the modern browsers. As you can see here https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please add below CSS

```
.header-back{
  width:25%;
}
form.back{
  width:100%; 
  padding-left:0px !important;
  padding-right:0px !important;
}
.heading .title{
  width:75%;
}
```

then change your heading div html to below

```
    <div class='heading'>
          <div class='title'> 
              Manual Control
          </div>
          <div class="header-back">
          <form method='post' action='/' class='back'>
              Back
          </form>              
          </div>
        </div>
```

then it will look like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to take the other answer, since it does solve all my requirements listed in my original post. The header works fine too with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```
    .heading div,
     .heading form{
     float:left;
     }

    .heading div{
      width:75%;
    }

    .heading form{
     width:25%;
    }
```